# How do you allow a textbox be null or a 5 digit number

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating a client object that is being written to a database.  This field is not required in the database.  I want to allow the field to be empty, or a 5 digit number.   My code below ensures that the field is a 5 digit number but I can not proceed with my continue with it being empty/null

```
try
{
    int outputValue = 0;
    bool isNumber = false;
    isNumber = int.TryParse(txtZip.Text, out outputValue);

    if (!isNumber)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Zip code must be a number");
    }
    else if (txtZip.Text.Length != 5)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Zip code must be 5 digits long");
    }
    else
    {
        ClientInformation client = new ClientInformation(
            txtFirstName.Text, 
            txtMiddleInitial.Text, 
            txtLastName.Text, 
            txtPhone.Text, 
            txtEmail.Text, 
            txtAddress.Text,
            txtCity.Text, 
            txtState.Text, 
            txtZip.Text, 
            datetimeDob.Text, 
            txtOccupation.Text, 
            txtEmployer.Text, 
            txtEmergencyContact.Text, 
            txtEmergencyContactRelationship.Text, 
            txtEmergencyContactPhone.Text, clientmed);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to check for this empty string ...`if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtZip.Text)) {...};`

Answer (score 2):

I usually find it easier to reason multiple conditions if I adopt a pattern of check-and-return-if-bad and finally(if nothing failed) do the good thing...

```
        if (!int.TryParse(txtZip.Text, out int x)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Zip code must be a number");
            return;
        }

        if (txtZip.Text.Length > 0 && txtZip.Text.Length != 5)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("If specified, Zip code must be 5 digits long");
            return;
        }
            
        try
        {
            ClientInformation client = new ClientInformation(txtFirstName.Text, txtMiddleInitial.Text, txtLastName.Text, txtPhone.Text, txtEmail.Text, txtAddress.Text,
                    txtCity.Text, txtState.Text, txtZip.Text, datetimeDob.Text, txtOccupation.Text, txtEmployer.Text, txtEmergencyContact.Text, txtEmergencyContactRelationship.Text, txtEmergencyContactPhone.Text, clientmed);
        }
```

Consider not using so many messageboxes; for example maybe make your zip a numericupdown (that you pad out to 5 digits) it a maskedtextbox, rather than annoying the user with a dialog they have to dismiss upon every error. Interrupting the users workflow with an endless sequence of error messages is so Symbian...

Comment: I'm still fairly new and want to try to write my code to a better standard, if possible. We just covered try/catch a few weeks ago.  So if I'm understanding you correctly, enter error checking in try,  catch exceptions in catch, and finally do my object instantiation and database writing?

Comment: I've just jiggled it around a little to move thenifa out of the try because they're unlikely to fail in any serious way. It's a bit topic "how to structure a program well", but generally consistency is more important than any particular pattern.. and one thing you should be consistent about is: think of every common thing that can go wrong and test for it, and prove the data good, then work with the data, rather than using exceptions for every trivial thing- exceptions are expensive and shouldn't really be used for normal program flow alteration.

Comment: I wouldn't say "yes" to your rule there any more than I would say "always drive round corners in the neighborhood using the lowest gear" - that sort of blanket rule is made up for newbies to make sure they don't do anything stupid- it's not a mantra for life. Try code that may fail, catch errors you want to deal with, finally release any unmanaged resources you used.. is about the only pattern to be memorized here

Answer (score 1):

While Caius' way, is probably the right way in terms of clean code and user experience, you can achieve what you want with this code:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtZip.Text) && !isNumber)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Zip code must be a number");
    }
    else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtZip.Text) && txtZip.Text.Length != 5 && txtZip.Text.Length != 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Zip code must be 5 digits long");
    } else // etc
```

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason for multiple messages as "Zip code must be 5 digits long" conveys the point for all input cases.

There are two validation conditions non-whitespace entries:

1. Every entered character must be a valid digit in the given culture.
2. The count of valid digits must be equal to five.

The current validation using:

1. `isNumber = int.TryParse(txtZip.Text, out outputValue);`
2. `txtZip.Text.Length > 0 && txtZip.Text.Length != 5`

will fail if the user enters a minus sign (i.e. "-1234") or if entry is padded with spaces (i.e. "1...." where "." is a placeholder for " ").

You may be able to overcome these fail points with further input processing and logic conditions. However I find it clearer to use code that explicitly performs the two validation conditions defined above.

First, set the [TextBox.MaxLength Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textbox.maxlength?view=netcore-3.1) to limit the user to entering a maximum five characters.

```
// define the valid input digits. do not be tempted to use char.IsDigit method
// in determining if the input is a valid digit as the user could enter a digit
// from another culture that would not be valid for this code.
// these digits could also be extracted from CultureInfo,InvariantCulture.NumberFormat.NativeDigits

char[] validDigits = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };


if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtZip.Text)) // actually IsNulOrEmptyOrWhitespace
{
    txtZip.Text = string.Empty; // ensure its empty
}
// use the Enumerable.Count extension Method
// to count the number of valid digits. 
else if (txtZip.Text.Count((c) => validDigits.Contains(c)) != 5)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Zip code must be 5 digits long");
    return;
}

ClientInformation client = new ClientInformation(.....
```

It should be mentioned that this code does not ensure that a valid ZipCode was entered (the entry could be: "00000" or an undefined code), it just ensures that the format is correct.

Regarding the usage the `try-block`,  it is preferable to only enclose code that can fail unpredictably and then only if you can recover successfully from the failure. None of the code you showed should fail except for possibly an out-of-memory error; if that happens, you got other issues to deal with.  This assumes that the `ClientInformation` constructor does not throw an exception which no constructor should do.